# What is the usage and purpose of $any() type cast in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

i Angular.io site i saw this title:

The $any() type cast function
Sometimes a binding expression triggers a type error during AOT compilation and it is not possible or difficult to fully specify the type. To silence the error, you can use the $any() cast function to cast the expression to the any type as in the following example:

```
<p>The item's undeclared best by date is: {{$any(item).bestByDate}}</p>
```

but there is no longer description or benefit or practice in it.

1. What's that technically?
2. When we have to and need to use of this
   stuff?

Answer (score 1):

"fullTemplateTypeCheck" in the "angularCompilerOptions" of the project's enabled. Angular compiler will be stricter when checking your templates type and catch any errors before they cause crashes at runtime.

> $any() can be used in binding expressions to disable type checking of
>   this expression. This is really similar to as any in TypeScript, and allows expressions that work at runtime but do not type-check.

[For More Info Check this:](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/01/11/what-is-new-angular-5.2/)

Comment: please confirm the question if it is useful thank you @chellappan